# Adding a unique class to items in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, class, foreach, unique

I've got a bunch of images in a folder called img and am trying to do a foreach loop to loop over them and output them to the screen, but then adding a unique class to each image.

Here's what I have so far but it says `$i` is undefined, so I'm not sure I'm on the right track. I'm very new to this.

```
   $dir = "img/gallery/*.jpg";
   $classes = array('promotional', 'beaches', 'volunteers');
   $images = glob( $dir );

   foreach ( $images as $image ):
   $class = $classes[$i++ % 3];
   echo '
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mix ' . $class . '">
          <div class="portfolio-item">
              <div class="shot-item">
                  <a class="overlay lightbox" href="' . $image . '">;
                      <img src="' . $image . '" />;
                      <i class="lnr lnr-plus-circle item-icon"></i>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   ';
   endforeach;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$i = 0;` before loop

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the `foreach` a little bit like so:

```
$dir = "img/gallery/*.jpg";
$classes = array('promotional', 'beaches', 'volunteers');
$images = glob( $dir );
$i = 0;

foreach ( $images as $x => $image ):
$class = $classes[$i++ % 6];
echo '
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mix ' . $class . '-' . $x . '">
       <div class="portfolio-item">
           <div class="shot-item">
               <a class="overlay lightbox" href="' . $image . '">;
                   <img src="' . $image . '" />;
                   <i class="lnr lnr-plus-circle item-icon"></i>
               </a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
';
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Tidies it up nicely!

Comment: @AlexKenny added splash58's comment so you won't get an undefined error message.

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed I had put % 6 with only 3 items in my array!

Comment: Is there any way of defining which images get which class?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could you maybe show an example?

Comment: Well currently, with this setup, it puts "promotional" on the first image it finds, then "beaches" on the next and "volunteers" on the third, then starts again. I wondered if there was a way of setting a particular class for a particular image. If that makes sense. Like if I had 3 images called promotional-1, promotional-2 and promotional-3 and 2 other images called beaches-1 and volunteers-1, how could I specify that the promotional ones should have the class promotional and so forth?

Comment: @AlexKenny If those are the filenames of the images then you can just use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to retrieve the class name you need. Just use the first element of the resulting array. Something like `explode('-', $filename);` will result in something like `array('promotional', '1')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way would be using two class rather than one unique.

First class will be use to detect item/content type,
and second will be unique to identify uniquely.

By doing this it will give you more control over content.

Here is little bit modification.

```
$dir = "img/gallery/*.jpg";
$classes = array('promotional', 'beaches', 'volunteers');
$images = glob( $dir );

foreach ( $images as $index => $image ):
$class = $classes[$i++ % 6];
echo "
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mix my-list-item-{$class} image-id-{$index}">
      <div class="portfolio-item">
          <div class="shot-item">
              <a class="overlay lightbox" href="' . $image . '">;
                  <img src="' . $image . '" />;
                  <i class="lnr lnr-plus-circle item-icon"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
";
endforeach;
```

What changes:

1. Changes single quote(') to double quote(") to be able to parse variable inside string, like this {$class} or simply like this $class
2. added class to identify type of item, my-list-item-{$class} : will result like this this my-list-item-promotional
3. added class to identify as a unique item, image-id-{$index} : will result like this image-id-5

#### **Use in css or js**

**CSS:**

```
.my-list-item-promotional{background: green;}
.my-list-item-promotional.image-id-2{background: yellow;}
```

This will provide all promotional type content background green except item number 2

You can use jQuery to select element like CSS does.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define your own `$i`; it already exists as the index of the `$images` array.

After you do `$images = glob( $dir );`, `$images` will be a numerically indexed array. So instead of explicitly incrementing a counter variable like this:

```
foreach ( $images as $image ):
    $class = $classes[$i++ % 3];
```

You can just use the index from the array like this:

```
foreach ( $images as $i => image ):
    $class = $classes[$i % 3];
```